# How to convert 256 colors palettized RGBA image data to NSImage

Tags: image, nsimage, palette, rgba, nsbitmapimagerep

I'm a newbie developer and I need your help with something that is probably trivial for you.

I have an image data in this pixel format: 256 colors palettized RGBA. It comes from FFmpeg `(PIX_FMT_PAL8)` and it's explained this way:

> PIX_FMT_RGB32 is handled in an endian-specific manner. An RGBA
>   color is put together as:
>
> (A << 24) | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B
>
> This is stored as BGRA on little-endian CPU architectures and ARGB on big-endian CPUs.
>
> When the pixel format is palettized RGB (PIX_FMT_PAL8), the palettized image data is stored in AVFrame.data[0].
>
> The palette is transported in AVFrame.data[1], is 1024 bytes long (256 4-byte entries) and is formatted the same as in PIX_FMT_RGB32 described above (i.e., it is also endian-specific). Note also that the individual RGB palette components stored in AVFrame.data[1] should be in the range 0..255.

AVFrame struct contains `uint8_t *data[4]` and `int linesize[4]` and they are described simply with:

> - `uint8_t *data[4]` = pointer to the picture planes
> - four components are given, that's all.
> - the last component is alpha
> - `int linesize[4]` = number of bytes per line

I have the AVFrame struct with all the needed data but I don't know how to handle it.
I need to create a NSImage from this image data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a palettized image, the pixels contain a one byte value, which is an index into the palette. The palette has 256 entries.

Pixels are stored starting at address AVFrame.data[0]; the palette is stored starting at address AVFrame.data[1].

So to get the 4 bytes pixel value for the pixel at (X, Y), you can use first:

```
uint8_t Index= AVFrame.data[0][X + AVFrame.linesize[0] * Y];
```

to get the index into the palette, and then

```
int RGBA= ((int*)AVFrame.data[1])[Index];
```

to get the RGBA encoded value.